# Processing.js nested for loop

Tags: processing.js

My first question on stackoverflow.  Hope it's not too dumb.

The following code not working the way I hoped it would.
subjects.txt is just lines with paired values, like '25,something' and '26,somethingelse'.
My nested for loop is supposed to step through and print the first three lines, and each time it is supposed to adjust the value of j (the y coordinate) so that the lines print one underneath another. The code below doesn't do that, instead all three lines print on top of one another and then the j (y coordinate) value is updated until it reaches 500.

How can I structure the loop to have the desired effect?  Thanks so much for any help...

```
String[] whatever = loadStrings("subjects.txt");

PFont font;
font = loadFont("Arial-Black-14.vlw"); 
noLoop();

textFont(font);
background(255);
size(500,500); 
fill(0);

for (i=1; i <= 3; i++;) {
for (int j = 20; j < 500; j = j+15) {
text(whatever[i], 30, j);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean you meant to spread out the first three lines from "subjects.txt" horizontally, and re-print this set vertically from 20 to 500?

To do that, you loop needs to do this:

```
for (int j=20; j < 500; j++)
  for (int i=i; i <= 3; i++)
    outText += whatever[i]+"\t";
  text(outText, 30,j);
```

Although I'm not sure I understand your question properly... is subjects.txt more than three lines long? Are you wanting to print all of the lines from subjects.txt?

Comment: thanks yasashiku - i didn't see your response... solved this problem a different way a while ago.  appreciate the help!